# Essential supremum of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Rudin's book RCA, it says that(pg 69) that:

If $f$ is a complex valued continuous functions on $R^k$ with compact support, then the essential supremum of $f$ is the same as the actual supremum. That is,
$||f||_{\infty} = \sup_{R^k} |f|$.

Is it necessary for $f$ to be compactly supported to have $||f||_{\infty} = \sup_{R^k} |f|$?

Comment: It is not necessary, $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ satisfies the condition but is not compactly supported.

Comment: If a function is continuous there is no difference between the supremum and the essential supremum, regardless of support. The discussion on p69. is in the context of $L^p$ spaces, so he just wants to make the point that you can drop the equivalence class part.